# what is happens to my data after upgrade 20.04.1

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, do-release-upgrade, unattended-upgrades, partial-upgrade

I was useing ubuntu 20.04 , update was showing up to 20.04.1
but

What will happens to all data,file,program,desktop themes after upgrade 20.04.1

Comment: You probably meant 22.04.1, because there is no upgrade to 20.04.1, and also it is already at 20.04.5.

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re upgrading from and to … but *you must have backups of your data* whether or not you’re upgrading, but even more so when you do. So back it all up, do the upgrade and if there are problems, just restore your data from backup.

Answer (score 1):

> I was useing ubuntu 20.04 , update was showing up to 20.04.1

No. You are using 20.04.5 (and if not need to update 1st) and the upgrade is showing 22.04.1.

> What will happens to all data,file,program,desktop themes after upgrade 20.04.1

Generally nothing. 3rd party software are disabled but that is it. Need to enable it afterwards.

But ... why ask? You have backups and know how to restore them. Unless you do not care about your data. I have a daily backup with an automated sync to my google drive. Takes 10 minutes to setup. Having to conclude afterwards something went wrong will take a lot more time to fix. With its own risks. Making 1 mistake is bad but forgivable. Making a mistake fixing that mistake is stupid.

Comment: yes I'm using 20.04.5, but why they are asking to upgrade to 20.04.1

Comment: And what will happens to data in computer , it go away or not